# iCheck check boxes are not visible in print

Tags: javascript, jquery, icheck

I am using iCheck check boxes, everything works fine in browser and coding,
But when i am trying to print page then checkbox are not at all visible,

```
<label>
   <input type="radio" name="ques_apti" class="icheck" data-radio="iradio_square-red" value="12">
</label>
```

Is there any way to print check boxes on paper?

Even if you just right click on this page http://icheck.fronteed.com/ and print, this page also doesn't show check boxes in print,

Any solution or workaround?

Thank you,

Comment: Use a print stylesheet and put the classes in that?

Answer (score 2):

I added this to the print.css and it worked :

```
@media print {
    input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
        opacity: 1 !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I devised a quick fix. If you would like to print with the default styling of the checkboxes, you can simply change the opacity of the checkbox to 1 and back to 0. The iCheck plugin sets the opacity to 0. (I was using the print plugin to print a certain div on the page)

```
$('input.flat:checkbox').css('opacity', '1');
$('#myDiv').print();
$('input.flat:checkbox').css('opacity', '0');
```